# Tracking changes in text file with PHP

Tags: php, server-push

I have a PHP script that has to reload a page on the client (server push) when something specific happens on the server. So I have to listen for changes. My idea is to have a text file that contains the number of page loads for the current page. So I would like to monitor the file and as soon as it is modified, to use server push in order to update the content on the client. The question is how to track the file for changes in PHP?

Comment: PHP has no such mechanism short of continually polling a file to see if the timestamps/size has changed. Most modern OSes have notification systems you could potentially hook into, however, which'll do the heavy lifting for you. But since you don't say which OS you're on...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet%5F%28programming%29    This might help

Comment: But wouldn't the reload of the page cause the counter to change as well? So you would end up with a continually refreshing page.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<?php
while(true){
    $file = stat('/file');
    if($file['mtime'] == time()){
        //... Do Something Here ..//
    }
    sleep(1);
}
```

This will continuously look for a change in the modified time of a file every second. If you don't constrain it you could kill your disk IO and may need to adjust your ulimit.

Comment: Make sure you include something to eventually break that loop!  That'll bring a machine crashing down in no time.

Answer (score 0):

This will check your file for a change:

```
<?php
  $current_contents = "";  

  function checkForChange($filepath) {
    global $current_contents;

    $new_contents = file_get_contents($filepath);
    if (strcmp($new_contents, $current_contents) {
      $current_contents = $new_contents;
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
```

But that will not solve your problem. The php file that serves the client finishes executing before the rendered html is sent to the client. That client will need to call back to some php file to check for a change... and since that is also a http request, the file will finish executing and forget anything in memory.

In order to properly solve this, you'll probably have to back off the idea of checking a file. Either the server needs to know when and how to contact currently connected clients, or those clients need to poll a lightweight service at a regular interval.

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of hacky but what about creating a cron job that sucks in the page, stores it in a scope or table, and then simply compares it every 30 seconds?